# Is DAI-style permit safe to use?

Tags: erc-20, dai

Here's a snippet from the DAI stablecoin permit function:

```
uint wad = allowed ? uint(-1) : 0;
allowance[holder][spender] = wad;
emit Approval(holder, spender, wad);
```

(full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/makerdao/dss/blob/3f30552a586264b32ebdb5bac94ba67020282e53/src/dai.sol#L122-L144))

Differently from the [EIP-2612](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612) which defines a "value" for the allowance DAI's approach appears to approve an unlimited allowance for the spender address.

Is it safe to permit a protocol to spend DAI on my behalf?

If not, to which use cases is DAI-style permit targeted to?

Comment: maybe not the answer you look for: but generally "Is it safe to permit a protocol to spend **TOKENS** on my behalf"? it depends on the protocol. If the protocol is only a smart contract and you see the source code and trust that the contract is bug-free and will only transfer the token based on defined logic and transparent actions/conditions then no harm in doing it (but you can see there is too many "AND"s).

Comment: it is not erc20 but they use also approve all in their protocol which is similar to unlimited allowance https://opensea.io/blog/tutorials/sell-your-crypto-collectibles-without-paying-gas/

Comment: @MajdTL Nicely put, there are too many "ANDs" for trusting a protocol with unlimited allowance approval. It's more flexible, sure, but more riskier if any bug is found in the protocol. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recent BADGER protocol exploit, in which US$120 million were stolen, provides more insight to this question.

According to the [source](https://rekt.news/badger-rekt/):

> Infinite approval means unlimited trust - something which we know we shouldn’t do in DeFi.

US$120 million were taken in various forms of wBTC and ERC20 in a front-end attack, in which an unknown party inserted additional approvals to send users' tokens to their own address.

Rumours that the project’s Cloudflare account was compromised have been circulating